# How do I get the first column of the current buffer after scrolling horizontally?

Tags: buffers, cursor

In the normal case, the first column is 1. But after a command like `z10l` to scroll rightward now the first column visible is `11` instead of `1`. How do I get this `11`?

My trying: I found that `vim.fn.virtcol('.')` can give what I want **only if** I place my cursor at the first visible column after `z10l` in the first place. Now the problem becomes what should I pass to `virtcol`.

Comment: It looks like `:help WinScrolled-event` might be of help.

Comment: @romainl Thanks for the documentation, but is it possible to get the info without an autocmd?

Comment: try `:echo winsaveview()['leftcol']`

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Insane! This is the answer I think! If you have time you could write this into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
:echo winsaveiew()['leftcol']
```

That should always show the correct column for the left border.